# Convert date to number in excel; e.g. Jan-01 -> 1/1

Tags: excel, date, date-formatting

Having an issue with excel mistaking address information for date.

I have a column that contains apartment/floor information, generally in the format of a single digit, or maybe a digit and a number. A number of entries however are in the format of 4/5; 5/12; etc. which is causing issue as excel is reading them as a date and displaying as 4-May; or May-12.

I need to convert these back to the desired format, however within excel I can only seem to convert to 4/5/2017; or 45537; etc.

Any ideas on how to achieve the above without having to manually parse the entire document would be appreciated.

Comment: Write a macro to write a single quote **`'`** in the beginning of each cell where you have data in that particular column. Single quote will force those cells to be in text format.

Comment: @ManishChristian This will not work because excel will already have changed the content of the formula bar to a date. So effectively the apostrophe will be placed before 4/5/2017 instead of 4/5.

Comment: Make sense. Then in this case I would suggest format that whole column with Text type before you even put any data to that column. I've tested it and its working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless I am mistaken in what you are trying to achieve, put a "`" in front of your entry to display exactly what you type.

Comment: Thanks for this - quite basic but did the trick to convert back to a proper string!

Comment: Excellent to here!  Just remember to make this comment as an "answer" to close out your question.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I have assumed that you already have a column filled with addresses. However if you are ENTERING the addresses, it is best to use apostrophe (') before the address is entered or format the column as text as ManishChristian and Krunch has suggested

Assuming your addresses are in column A:

```
=IF(LEFT(CELL("format",A1),1)="D",TEXT(A1,"d/m"),A1)
```

This works for 1/1, 4/5, 5/12.

Please test check the formula with different types of addresses you may be having to ensure it does not result in undesired outputs.

Comment: Thanks for the input, used this in combination with the above to resolve!